# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 10 - Deleting Unneeded Files

Tags: python

The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter10/):

> It’s not uncommon for a few unneeded but humongous files or folders to
> take up the bulk of the space on your hard drive. If you’re trying to
> free up room on your computer, you’ll get the most bang for your buck
> by deleting the most massive of the unwanted files. But first you have
> to find them.
>
> Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for
> exceptionally large files or folders—say, ones that have a file size
> of more than 100MB. (Remember that to get a file’s size, you can use
> os.path.getsize() from the os module.) Print these files with their
> absolute path to the screen.

My solution:

```
import send2trash
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    while True:
        basedir = Path(input("Please enter a folder to search: "))
        if not basedir.is_dir():
            print("This path does not exist.")
            continue
        else:
            for filename in basedir.rglob("*"):
                if filename.stat().st_size > 100000000:
                    print(f"{filename} is {filename.stat().st_size} bytes, sending to trash...")
                    send2trash.send2trash(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- > Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for exceptionally large files ...

  Your code only scans the single folder. It doesn't walk a folder tree.
- > ... or folders

  That is perhaps the trickiest part, and the problem statement is very unclear, perhaps intentionally. A size of a folder, as reported by `stat()` is usually very small. The task - likely - is to sum the sizes of files in the entire tree undeer a given folder. and report it if necessary.
- > But first you have to find them.

  The task is to find those files. Don't `send2trash.send2trash` them right away.

In any case, `os.walk` is your friend.

Comment: The OP used `.rglob("*")`, not `.glob"*")`, so it **will** recurse through subdirectories.  It is not just scanning a single folder.

Answer (score 2):

- Don’t put magic numbers in your code. Use constants (`FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 100 * 1024 * 1024`) at the top of the module (below the imports).
- 100 MB = 1024 * 1024 bytes, not 1000000 bytes. That’s a MiB.
- You’re calling `stat().st_size` two times. Make a habit of creating a variable in such cases that contains the calculated / fetched value.
- I see strings in Python most of the time enclosed in single quotes (‘), not in double quotes (“). Not sure if and where this is documented. PEP8 explicitly *doesn’t* take position in this matter (it just states that you should choose either one).