# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 10 - Deleting Unneeded Files Alternative

Tags: python

This is another solution to a [previously asked question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280426/automate-the-boring-stuff-chapter-10-deleting-unneeded-files).
The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter10/):

> It’s not uncommon for a few unneeded but humongous files or folders to
> take up the bulk of the space on your hard drive. If you’re trying to
> free up room on your computer, you’ll get the most bang for your buck
> by deleting the most massive of the unwanted files. But first you have
> to find them.
>
> Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for
> exceptionally large files or folders—say, ones that have a file size
> of more than 100MB. (Remember that to get a file’s size, you can use
> os.path.getsize() from the os module.) Print these files with their
> absolute path to the screen.

My solution:

```
import send2trash, os
import pyinputplus as pyip

def get_size(basedir, find_size):
    large_folders = {}
    large_files = {}
    for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
        folder_size = 0
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            folder_size += os.path.getsize(filepath)
            file_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
            if file_size > find_size:
                large_files[filepath] = file_size
        if folder_size > find_size:
            large_folders[folder] = folder_size
    return large_folders, large_files

def main():
    while True:
        basedir = input("Please enter a folder to search: ")
        if not os.path.exists(basedir):
            print("This path does not exist.")
            continue
        else:
            find_size = pyip.inputInt(prompt="Enter the size in bytes of the folders and files to file: ")
            large_folders, large_files = get_size(basedir, find_size)
            print("Large folders:")
            for folder, size in large_folders.items():
                print(f"{folder} is {size} bytes")
            print("Large files:")
            for file, size in large_files.items():
                print(f"{file} is {size} bytes")
            while True:
                deletedir = input("Enter the directory of the file or folder you want to delete, or enter nothing to choose another folder to search: ")
                if not deletedir:
                    break
                elif not os.path.exists(deletedir):
                    print("This path does not exist.")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Deleting path...")
                    send2trash.send2trash(deletedir)
                    continue
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing serious here, you improved it a lot since the [last time](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280426/automate-the-boring-stuff-chapter-10-deleting-unneeded-files).

---

`for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(basedir):`
can be
`for folder, _, filenames in os.walk(basedir):`
since you never use `subfolders`, there is no need to load the reader with yet another name.

```
if not os.path.exists(basedir):
    print("This path does not exist.")
    continue
else:
```

`else` is redundant and adds an extra level of nesting.

```
if not deletedir:
    break
elif not os.path.exists(deletedir):
```

Again no need to write `elif`, just `if` will fit.

```
continue
    else:
```

Same story. Try adding blank lines after control statements like `break` and `continue` to see where the execution can end preemptively.

Function `get_size()` doesn't get any size, it gets dicts of large files and folders and should be named accordingly, e.g. `get_large_files()`.

`find_size` again, doesn't tell what the name is for, could be `min_size`.

---

Overall pretty clean code, keep it up!